# What is the Best method to http transfer a file from the client to a server, in Java 1.5?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts

What is the Best method to http transfer a file from the client to a server, in Java 1.5?

Comment: Easiest, most robust, most feature-ful? Define best.

Answer (score 9):

I'd use [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [URLConnection](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).